# Shell script to read values from a file and to compare them with another value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a shell script, where I read in a number and it compares the number with the numbers in another file.
Here is an example:

I have a file called numbers.txt, which contains the following:

```
name;type;value;description
samsung;s5;1500;blue
iphone;6;1000;silver
```

I read in a number for example 1200. And it should print out the values from the file which are lesser than 1200(in my example it should print out 1000)

Here is the code that I started to write but I don't know how to finish it.

```
echo " Enter a number"
read num
if [ $numbersinthefile -le $num ]; then
echo "$numbersinthefile"
```

I hope I defined my question properly. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter the number: "
read num

awk -F\; '$3 < '$num' {print $0;}' myfile
```

Comment: Good solution! It would be also good to quote num `'$3 < '"$num"' { ....`.

Comment: when I did this, compare don't work well. I don't know why.

Comment: @Incrivel Monstro Verde it works, but can you please explain how does this actually work? I don't quite get it.

Comment: -F\; is the delimiter (escaped). if $3 (field 3 from file) less than $num, show line from myfile

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first you use `sed` to remove first line then you use `cut` to get the actual number from line and you compare that number to the input.

```
echo " Enter a number"
read num

sed '1d' numbers.txt | while read line; do
   numbersinthefile=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f3);
   if [ $numbersinthefile -lt $num ]; then
      echo $line;
   fi
done
```

Comment: This method works too, thank you. Can you explain what does that '1d' mean? 
Also while read line reads elements from the numbers.txt line by line am I right?
And one more question, what should I do if I wanted to print out "No product" (or smth like that) if there were no values which are lesser than the number. 

I tried to put // else echo  "No product"// after the "eho $line;", but it wrote "No product" 5 times.